# URLCache and URLSession.shared

Tags: ios, swift

My networking layer uses `URLSession` to make it's network calls. For example, I need to get a list of `Restaurant` data from my server:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
  guard let data = data, 
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        let dictionaries = json as? [String: Any] else { fatalError() }

  // ...
}
```

For simplicity, let's assume `dictionaries` gives the following:

```
[
  ["id": 1, "name": Nuba"], 
  ["id": 2, "name": "Meat & Bread"], 
  ["id": 3, "name": "Chipotle"]
]
```

Let's say I hit the same `url` endpoint again. Will the default `URLCache` notice that and give me back the same data as before without actually doing a network request?

Comment: It likely should for a simple `GET` request like this, though it is subject to whatever headers the server includes in its responses. (It's also subject to poorly documented criteria, including things like not caching responses if they exceed 5% of the total cache size.) If you do a `POST`, though, it won't cache. I'd suggest getting a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) and watch what goes down the wire...